How to make players die when they step on a certain block using a command block?
I'm making a world and I need to know how to make a player die when they step on an orange wool (or other block).
How can I accomplish this using a command block?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

Pretty much just says he wants to cause as much pain as possible @Joachim otherwise why would he be intending on killing players when they step on a certain block?

Just fyi if piracy is removed and the question stands on its own, it stands on its own

I did not see the "minecraft free version" when I posted my answer.

@aytimothy I still don't get how your initial comment conveyed that message, but you're right about it being an on-topic question (I've made this mistake before :). I'll vote to reopen.

@Joachim It's still low-quality though. So the original close reason stands...

According to the Minecraft Wiki, you can use a command like this:
/execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ orange_wool run kill @s

This will, as all players (as @a) check at the player's position (at @s) to see if the block under the player is orange wool (if block ~ ~-1 ~ orange_wool (or also if block ~ ~-1 ~ wool 1 on bedrock edition)), and if that condition is true, run kill @s to kill the player.
The command above is derived from this example on the Minecraft Wiki.
